# Mvc 3 - Use the same view and viewmodel for standard and admin screen?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have two screens, a standard user screen and an admin screen.  The changes between the two are fairly minor - a few extra buttons and options on the admin screen.

As far as MVC best practices, is it better to:

1. Use the **same view and the same viewmodel** for both the admin and the standard user screen.  That way there is no code duplication, but I will have several if...else statements in the view and controller
2. Use **separate views and viewmodels** for the admin and user screens.  This leads to some code duplication, but is ultimately the most flexible if the screens end up diverging more than they currently are.
3. Some other great solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use seperate viewmodels and apply **inheritance** to your `ViewModel` .So you are not duplicating the code.

```
public class CustomerCreateViewModel
{
  //Here i i have properties common to both user and admin
  public string FirstName { set;get;}
  public string LastName { set;get;}
}
public class AdminCustomerCreateViewModel : CustomerCreateViewModel
{
  //This property is only for admin
  public string ReasonForFiring { set;get;}
}
```

I personally prefer to keep separate views because it makes things clean and more readable /maintainable. Now you have 2 separate ViewModels, so have separate views. You may consider render Partial Views (in both the views) as necessary

Comment: I think this is the best solution for me.  Thanks Shyju!

Answer (score 0):

This is really only a question you can answer.  You basically said it, if the changes are minor, then us a single view and wrap the administrative functions in if statements that check the users role.

However, I would only do that if there are no model changes between the admin and non-admin versions. Once you add additional model items, then I would suggest using seperate models and views.